# How to convert string to null or Nan in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this table where one of the column has string and integer, and I want to convert the string to integer as 0. How can I do this in python?
The column similar like this:

```
size
1
1
1
2
ABC
```

I expect it can be converted as:

```
size
1
1
1
2
0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for missing values instead strings, replace them by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and last convert to integers:

```
df['size'] = pd.to_numeric(df['size'], errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
   size
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `isinstance()` function?

```
test=["abc",1,2,3,"def"]
for x in test:
    if isinstance(x, str): print ("0")
    else: print (x)
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
0
```